# Is there a way to filter the columns I'm getting from CDS in a Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to filter the columns I'm getting from CDS in a Logic App, something similar to `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM table` instead of `SELECT * FROM table`.

I have tried `$select=Column1,Column2` in Filter Query without any success.

===== UPDATE =====

I'm dealing with large amounts of data and I'm trying to avoid getting throttled(Logic App Content throughput limit per 5 minutes: 600MB). Filtering out all the unnecessary fields means the Logic App will get only KB of data from CDS instead of hundreds of MB

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution works, could you please mark it as "accepted". Thanks in advance~

Comment: Hi! I haven't had the chance to try your solution yet, but it's on my "to do" list. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry Gogutz, I provided a solution which is not so easy. Please refer to the solution I provided under "Update", it's more simple than the previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I think it is difficult to implement if we just use a common action in logic app. But if we use liquid template, it will be easy, please refer to the steps I provdied below:

**1.** You need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account#create-integration-account) an integration account in your azure portal (I think "**Free**" pricing tier is enough)

**2.** In my logic app, I use "List records" action to get data from CDS. My data show like below:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://logic-apis-eastasia.azure-apim.net/apim/commondataservice/xxxxxxxxxx/$metadata#datasets('orgd46a4820.crm')/tables('activitypointers')/items",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "statecode": 1,
      "_statecode_label": "Completed",
      .......
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "statecode": 1,
      "_statecode_label": "Completed",
      .......
    },
    .....
  ]
}
```

For example, I just want two columns(`ItemInternalId` and `statecode`) of the data as your requirement.

To implement the requirment get two columns(`ItemInternalId` and `statecode`) of the data, we need to write a liquid template. The code show as below:

```
{
    "value": [
        {% for item in content %}
           {
                "ItemInternalId": "{{item.ItemInternalId}}",
                "statecode":"{{item.statecode}}"
           },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Please save the liquid template in local with `.liquid` as its suffix (such as `map.liquid`).

**3.** Go to your integration account and click "Maps".

[image]

Then click "Add" and upload the `map.liquid` to integration account.

[image]

**4.** Go to your logic app and click "Workflow settings" tab and choose the integration account which we created just now.
[image]

**5.** In your logic app designer, add a "[Transform json to json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#add-the-liquid-transformation-action)" action. Use the value from "List records" as the "Content" box and choose the map which we upload to integration account.
[image]

**6.** Run the logic app, we can see the result show as below (contains only two columns).
[image]

====================================**Update**================================

After "**List records**" action, we can use a "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the value from "**List records**".

[image]

Then use "[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action)" action to select the columns which you want.

[image]

Comment: @Huri Shen, I'm afraid this is not what I was looking for. I'm trying to limit the incoming data. Each CDS record has a large amount of data, but I'm only interested in the Id and the time the record was created. So I'm trying to filter this in the actual CDS connector. Parsing the JSON can take minutes for 500 rows.

Comment: @Gogutz Sorry I'm a little confused. According to your latest description in the comment, I think the solution I provided is for your requirement. You just need to change the `ItemInternalId` and `statecode` to `Id` and `createTime`. What are you worried about ? The duration of "Parse JSON" ?

Comment: @Huri Shen, Sorry for the late response. I'm dealing with large amounts of data and I'm trying to avoid getting throttled(Logic App Content throughput limit per 5 minutes: 600MB). Filtering out all the unnecessary fields means the Logic App will get only KB of data from CDS instead of hundreds of MB.